# What is wrong with this Stored Procedure Not Inserting Records

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

Stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `test`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `UpdateRelatedAccounts`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UpdateRelatedAccounts`()
BEGIN 
    DECLARE ssn_sel_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE primary_sel_id CHAR(36) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE secondary_sel_rel CHAR(36) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;

  DECLARE ssn_all_cur CURSOR FOR
  SELECT ac.ssn, ac.id AS primary_id, ac_b.id AS secondary_id FROM ssn ac LEFT JOIN ssn ac_b ON  ac.ssn =  ac_b.ssn WHERE ac.ssn NOT IN ('','000-00-0000') AND ac.id != ac_b.id;

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_rows = TRUE;

 OPEN ssn_all_cur;
 SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO num_rows;
    the_loop: LOOP
        FETCH  ssn_all_cur
        INTO ssn_sel_id, primary_sel_id, secondary_sel_rel;

        IF no_more_rows THEN
        CLOSE ssn_all_cur;
        LEAVE the_loop;
        END IF;     
      INSERT INTO `ssn_related` ( `ssn_primary`, `ssn_related` ) VALUES ( '44','44'); -- ( primary_sel_id, secondary_sel_rel );

  END LOOP the_loop;    
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The Structure of SSN table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `ssn` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ssn` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Maybe your `SELECT` statement returned no rows?

Comment: It is returning records, i have run it separately

Comment: At what point are you expecting the insert statement to execute? It's inside "the_loop", but at the end of the cursor rows, the logic is to exit "the_loop" so the insert will not execute then.

Comment: In the Loop it should insert Values if there are Rows Returned Else it will Jump out of the Loop

Comment: Do you set `SET autocommit=0;` somewhere in your initialization?

Comment: No, Above is the ALL code that is running for the StoredProc, i am just confused why the Insert Query is not firing, The Select Query for Cursor is Returning records but insert is not executing, i don`t know if something is wrong with the loop or what.